# smooth complete intersection 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,

I have been dealing with a problem and I could not find any tools to attack it. The problem is the following,

What extra conditions do I need to show that an affine  smooth complete intersection variety is connected?

thanks for the answer and sorry for the sloppiness

Comment: the problem deals with varieties which have dimension higher than 24. 

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for? In the affine case, it is usually difficult to say something is connected.

Comment: yes it is affine. 

Comment: I thought of homogenizing the vanishing ideal and use the exercise Chapter II 8.4 [Compelete Intersection] which involves Unimixedness Thm (but do I really need that my Ring is Cohen-Macaulay) . OR to do some Bertini type trick  since i have an equidimensional variety. Cut with "good" hyperplanes and try to end up with a curve it works specific cases but i cant prove it for general cases. 

I really appreciate the comment.